# Remove data binding in angular2

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angular

Angular 2 data binding is great but i can't seem to find a angular 2 way of removing data binding on specific variables. My reason for this is i started hooking my application up to indexed DB and it works but i can't allow the temporary cache (just an array of all the indexed DB values) to be subject to data binding (if it was then the temporary cache would no longer mirror the database) my database is on an angular2 service. now i have found a way of removing the data binding but it isn't exactly pretty my code is this

```
app.copy=function(item){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item,app.replacer),app.reviver);
}
app.reviver=function(key,value){
    if(value.fn){
        value=new Function(value.parameters,value.body);
    }else if(key==="time"){
        value= new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
};
app.replacer=function(key,value){
    if(typeof value ==="function"){
        value=value.toString(); 
        value={
            fn:true,
            parameters:value.match(/\(([\s\S]*?)\)/)[1].replace(/[\s\r\/\*]/g,""),
            body:value.match(/\{([\s\S]*)\}/)[1].replace(/[\t\r\n]/g,"")
        };
    }
    return value;
};
```

like i said it works but it isn't pretty. i can just run app.copy on the variables before they leave the cache so that they don't get data bound to anything. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to tell angular 2 this variable isn't suppose to be data bound. and if not then at least i was able to get my solution up here for others.

Answer (score 1):

If you establish "binding" imperatively you can stop the binding imperatively. There is currently no support in Angular2 to cancel a declarative binding imperatively.

- Bind the view only to fields of the component.
- Use observables in the service that fire an event when values change.
- In the component subscribe to the observable and update the fields in the component when values in the service change.
- Update values in the service when values change in the component.

Comment: The problem is that my variables are bound to a service. The service is accessed by multiple directives and some of those directives then use the variables they get from the database into their views which means if you look at the entire chain it ends up looking like service variable = >component variable = >some other variable that's changed. Now I'm not sure why because I didn't explicitly bind the variables but for some reason because of that chain when the bottom variable is changed so is the service variable.

Comment: The only way I've been able to get around that chain is by creating a new object using json stringify and parse.

Comment: Hard t tell by the information you provided. I'm also not used to use Angular with JS.

Comment: I would put my whole database script up but it's about 200 lines long. I know in angular 1 there was angular.copy that did basically just what I want copied the object without data bindings but angular 2 doesn't have an equivalent that I've found